# How to install 64bit simulator in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, 64-bit, ios-simulator

i need to test my app under 64bit ipad device. Earlier in Xcode you could choose simulators with 64bit description (or without it to run app on 32bit simulator), but now, since I have Xcode 6 I can't see any option or description that could tell me if simulator is 32 or 64 bit. Is there any way to download and install 64bit simulator, or any other solution to choose between 32 and 64 bit simulators?

Comment: did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Hi Deborah, unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure, but simulator has `i386` architecture and `armv7`/`armv7s` is validate only for device. So you need read device to test it.